# Make the comment flag dialog draggable again

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, comment-flags

The post flag dialog can be dragged. This is helpful when I'm writing a custom flag and want to be able to see the text behind the dialog to quote from it or to make sure that what I'm writing is accurate.

The comment flag dialog used to also be draggable (which was useful for all the same reasons that it's useful for the post flag dialog), but no longer is since the July 31st redesign.

Please make it draggable again.

Comment: Related, from 2011: [The new flagging dialog gets in the way](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/74976)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The redesigned dialog wasn't compatible with the Javascript used to drag the other flag popups, but it will be once again with the next production build.