# Can we have colour coding on our comment flags, for both user accounts and mod dashboards?

Tags: feature-request, comments, design, flags, moderator-tools

We don't have  colour coding on our flag summaries for comments:

[image]

But we have them for some post flags:

[image][image]

For the users [flagged summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/3956566) and from the back end of the user account, the mod dashboard, can we have the different types of flagged comments colour coded. (admittedly we could write a script)

It would make it easier when reviewing flag histories and account comment histories, for both users and mods.

Something like this (tidied up, white or black font):

[image]

Comment: This makes me want 7 flagging reasons, with different colors and a unicorn pop up once we open the flagging dialog.

Comment: @BhargavRao me too :) we could always ask [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew) to  do it for us

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created the userscript, read more and install on Stackapps: **[Comment Flag Type Colours](https://stackapps.com/questions/7995/comment-flag-type-colours)**

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: you're the super hero of scripts :)