# 'Unfriendly or unkind' flags not showing in post timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, timeline

With the new comment flagging which [rolled out today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754), we split 'rude or abusive' flags into:

- It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
- It's unfriendly or unkind.

However, the second flag, 'unfriendly or unkind' does not appear in the timeline of a post for moderators. This doesn't seem to be intentional, and unfortunately causes a few popular userscripts to break.

In addition, flags of that type which are *resolved* do not appear in the waffle bar, and there's no indication of the flags having ever existed when viewing the post.

<sup>A bit of [back-seat developer-ing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-seat_driver): It *looks* as though the new flag just needs to be marked as visible to community moderators.</sup>

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313756/349538) reports the same bug and according to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1027913) by an employee, this will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: @DonaldDuck No, it doesn't. This is asking about the moderator-only timeline view for posts; my answer there is about users' personal flag history.

Comment: It's the same root cause, @Sonic Donald - the flag was left out of the lists that tell... well, various things... that it exists and should be shown. It's been added, but there's been no production build in the last 9 hours, so no one's gonna see those flags outside of the mod dashboard until there is.