# 'Unfriendly or unkind' flag not showing in flag summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags

With the new comment flagging which [rolled out today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754), we have the option of:

> It's unfriendly or unkind.
>
> The comment violates our [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct#unfriendly-language).

However, after raising this flag, it does not appear in my flag summary.

Comment: Already reported in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313756/377214) to [Updated comment flagging - Supporting the new Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313754/updated-comment-flagging-supporting-the-new-code-of-conduct). It's been fixed, but the build just hasn't rolled out yet.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog, what am I missing here as to the duplicate mark?

Comment: Comment edits aren't loaded live. Sorry you had to see the previous revision of my comment.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog, so I read through the top ten answers.  Still don't see where it notes what you have mentioned?

Comment: I linked to the relevant answer in my comment. There's a comment from a dev saying it's been fixed and will be out in the next build.

Comment: I clicked the link in your comment, it goes to the main question.

Comment: Did you click on the first link ("this answer")?

Comment: Oh, there are two links there?  The dark blue and black are hard to distinguish.

Comment: The underline on links should make it clearly visible now.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog, Yep, makes a HUGE difference.