# Add links to anchors in Code of Conduct

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, code-of-conduct

It's possible to link to certain sections in the [Code of Conduct](/conduct). For example, the link https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct#unacceptable-behavior will scroll directly to the "Unacceptable Behavior" section. One Stack Exchange feature which already uses this is the [Comment Flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754/295232).

Since it's usually rather helpful to direct a user to a specific location in the Code of Conduct (even though they should ideally read the entire document), can we have a nice way to generate those links? Right now, I have to open the browser console to find out the `id` of the section I want to link to:

[image]

It would be nice if we had an easier way to do this, for example how [GitHub renders Markdown pages](https://github.com/charcoal-se/smokedetector#smokedetector). If you hover over a header, you get an icon with the link to the corresponding anchor:

[image]