# Use the same location for Submit button in the comment flag dialog as in the post flag dialog

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, comment-flags, flag-dialog

Something bothers me about the new [comment flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313754/295232): it's the only dialog with the submit button on the left. Can we please move it to the right:

[image]

like the post flag dialog:

[image]

and half a dozen other dialogs (close a question, various mod tools) I've checked?

<sub>If this was a deliberate choice based on some trend or A/B testing I've missed, I'm fine with the alternative where all submit buttons are moved to the left. I just want the UI to be consistent.</sub>

Comment: I'm not voting for this specific FR but I do support the request for consistency.

Comment: I think there was a goal of updating all the dialogs to be consistent with the new comment flagging dialog? I feel like someone pointed out that the comment flagging dialog just looked completely different from all thr others in general. That one probably follows the Stacks design models whereas the others don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, the post flag and the question close dialogs have been updated and now also show the submit button on the left side:

[image]

Since this question was posted mainly as a request for consistency, I consider it [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: I'm not a UX expert or anything but in my experience dialog buttons are usually either on the right or in the center. This new change is pretty much counter-intuitive. Plus, I think we flag/VTC posts way more than we flag comments.

Comment: Agreed. The action buttons on a modal dialog are generally placed on the right.

Comment: They are now inconsistent with suggested edits.