# Port the new comment flagging dialog design to other similar dialogs?

Tags: feature-request, design, flag-dialog

It looks beautiful and modern-fashioned. Can we have the same design in post flagging, post closing, review options, moderator options et cetera?

> [image: oOo]

Comment: This is definitely the intention, according to [this comment by animuson ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316903/move-the-submit-button-in-the-comment-flag-dialog-to-the-right#comment1038287_316903): "I think there was a goal of updating all the dialogs to be consistent with the new comment flagging dialog? I feel like someone pointed out that the comment flagging dialog just looked completely different from all thr others in general. That one probably follows the Stacks design models whereas the others don't."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An update has been rolled out today, and the post flag and question close dialogs have been updated to use the [Stacks design](https://stackoverflow.design/):

[image: new post flag dialog]

---

[image: new question close dialog]